# WebClient is attaching headers to downloaded files

Tags: c#, webclient

I'm trying to download objects from OpenStack via GET.
The files download normally, except that WebClient is attaching headers to every single one of them at the very beginning, like this:

```
-------------------------------28947758029299
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""; filename="v30fDviSwYNfLlN0-a0D0w9pi.zip"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

This is my code:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient ();
client.Headers.Set ("X-Auth-Token", OktawaveApi.Token);

// Download progress
client.DownloadProgressChanged += delegate(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e) {
    progressCallback (e.ProgressPercentage);
};

// Download completed.
client.DownloadFileCompleted += delegate(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e) {
    completeCallback (true);
};

client.DownloadFileAsync (new Uri(OktawaveApi.StorageURL + "/" + parent.Name + "/" + Name), targetPath);
```

Is there any way to deal with that?

Comment: Can you show us what the server response looks like, e.g. looking at it via Wireshark? If it's claiming a multi-part response, it could be that WebClient isn't set up for that...

Comment: It is indeed multipart response http://shover.us/oe2sYc